# How to check if AHCI or IDE is enabled from the operating system using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, bios

Suppose In BIOS, SATA Configuration is set to AHCI or IDE Enabled, then is there anyway to check if AHCI or IDE is enabled from the operating system(Windows XP,7) through a batch file ?

Comment: After searching a bit it seems that there isn't even a way to check in during a windows run without a batch-file...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this script can help you or not,but anyway you can give a try and tell us the results that you will get after its execution :

```
@echo off 
Title Generate a text report for Devices manager
Mode con cols=80 lines=3
cls & color 0A & echo.
Set "LogFile=DeviceManager.txt"
Set "AHCI_LOG=AHCI_Log.txt"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
If Exist "%AHCI_LOG%" Del "%AHCI_LOG%"
echo       Please wait a while we generate the report in "%LogFile%" .....
start /wait msinfo32 /report "%LogFile%"
Find /I "AHCI" "%LogFile%" >> "%AHCI_LOG%"
start "" notepad "%AHCI_LOG%"
```

Comment: Above code is not exactly telling if AHCI or IDE is enabled. Its just generating bunch of log which it took from system information
Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @AkhilChalla You are welcome it's just a try ! me too i'm looking for it ! so we have to search again ! don't give up man ! (-_°)